# Android cannot find symbol BuildConfig

Tags: java, android, buildconfig, android-buildconfig

I have two modules, A and B. A added B as dependency. BuildConfig is generated in B, while being used in both A and B. No error shows in Android Studio, and the app can be installed successfully. But when making the whole project from command line, it shows the error "Cannot find symbol" on line "import com.package.b.BuildConfig". The odd thing is this only occurs on module B, but not module A. Note that the package name is correct and the app can normally run.

```
Module A
  |____com.package.a
        |____Class X
Module B
  |____com.package.b
        |____Class Y
        |____Class Z
        |____BuildConfig(generated)
```

Comment: can you update your question with project folder structure for better understanding. Also from which directory you are giving build command?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Parmesh the build command is triggered in the root dir of the project

Comment: `Note that the package name is correct...`  Q: *WHICH* name: "BuildConfig" or "BuildCongfig"?